# Android Java sound recorded with AudioRecord has noise when played

Tags: java, android, audio-streaming, audiotrack, audiorecord

I'm recording voice using `AudioRecord`, send it to server, receive it on both Android and Web. On Android, I'm playing the audio using `AudioTrack`, and there's a "tttttt" noise. On web, such noise doesn't seem to exist, maybe web API changes it to another more comfortable noise.

I'm recording voice and sending it so server like this:

```java
recorder = new AudioRecord(audioSource, sampleRateInHz, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);
int audioSession = recorder.getAudioSessionId();
NoiseSuppressor.create(audioSession);
AutomaticGainControl.create(audioSession);
AcousticEchoCanceler.create(audioSession);
...
try {
    int bytesRead;
    int count = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    while (isRecording) {
        bytesRead = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

        // skip first 2 buffers to eliminate "click sound"
        if (bytesRead > 0 && ++count > 2) {

            // I'm manually adding wav header to make it playable on web
            byte[] combined = new byte[wavHeaders.length + buffer.length];
            System.arraycopy(wavHeaders, 0, combined, 0, wavHeaders.length);
            System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, combined, wavHeaders.length, buffer.length);

            socket.emit("voice", combined);
        }
    }
    recorder.stop();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And this is how I'm playing the audio:

```java
player = new AudioTrack.Builder()
        .setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                // .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                .build())
        .setAudioFormat(new AudioFormat.Builder()
                .setEncoding(audioFormat)
                .setSampleRate(sampleRateInHz)
                .setChannelMask(outputChannelConfig)
                .build())
        .setBufferSizeInBytes(bufferSize)
        .build();
...
player.play();
...
public void addPlay(byte[] audioBuffer) {
    player.write(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.length, 0);
}
...
try {
    addPlay((byte[]) args[0]);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

## Update:

I noticed by removing the generated header, the "ttttt" noise goes away, but I need to in order to be playable on web.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the WAV format, but I would expect to have the header only at the beginning of the stream and not with every buffer.

Comment: @dev.bmax I'm also playing the data on web platform, and it seems like I can't play it without generating header.

Comment: you didn't get what @dev.bmax meant: you are saving the header again and again, with each little block of samples you read. So you're interrupting your written audio by yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write audio data without the header by specifying offset in the `audioBuffer`, something like

```
int audioOffset = wavHeaders.length;
int audioLength = audioBuffer.length - wavHeaders.length;
player.write(audioBuffer, audioOffset, audioLength, 0);
```